# Can't access public synonyms after setting current_schema

Tags: oracle10g

I need to get a script working for ordinary users, within the schema of a more privileged account. I'm using set current_schema to accomplish that. However, I'm finding that public synonyms don't work once I've altered the schema - I can't access a table in a third different schema unless I qualify it:

```
>select count(*) from my_table;

  COUNT(*)
----------
     79982

>alter session set current_schema = admin_account;

Session altered.

>select count(*) from my_table;
select count(*) from my_table
                     *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist


>select count(*) from other_account.my_table;

  COUNT(*)
----------
     79982
```

Is there any way to get the synonym working again?

Answer (score 1):

`Public synonyms` are accessible to `all users`. However each user must have appropriate privileges on the underlying object in order to use the `synonym`.Check the priviledges for `admin_account` on table `my_table`

Comment: Sorry, I should've said - if I log in directly using admin_account the synonym works fine. I'm beginning to wonder whether it might be a bug in 10g - it doesn't happen when I try the same setup in 11g.